# Dynamic Variable Name In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I'm trying to do a loop function that will get lyrics verses from array. I do have a working function but not with dynamic variable. All that i want is dynamic var name in a way. In Array Item There Is Values From "ve1" up to "ve20".
So I need to get this ve[i] like showed bellow but its not working how its supposed to.

```
function testingLyrics(){
  for (let i = 0; i < allMusic[indexNumb - 1].lyrics.length; i++) {
    if(allMusic[indexNumb - 1].lyrics.ve[i].stamp){

      /* Action */

  }}
}
```

The Array Looks Like That

```
var allMusic = [
    {
    lyrics:{
      ve1:{
        ls: "The club isn't the best place to find a lover",
      },
      ve2:{
        ls: "So the bar is where I go",
      },
      ve3:{
        ls: "Me and my friends at the table doing shots",
      },
     },
    },
    {
    lyrics:{
      ve1:{
        ls: "I've been having a good time",
      },
      ve2:{
        ls: "Man, I feel just like a rockstar (ayy, ayy)",
      },
      ve3:{
        ls: "All my brothers got that gas",
      },
     },
    },
]
```

Comment: You need to create a string key `lyrics[\`ve${i+1}\`]`

Comment: is the structure fixed, or can you rewrite it to have the lyrics in an array?

Comment: Also note the your code is trying to read `lyrics.length` and lyrics is an object and has no length.

Comment: It'd be much simpler if the "lyrics" properties were arrays and not objects. Any time you find yourself with (essentially) numeric keys like in your example, it's weird not to use a plain old array.

Comment: also [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Some days you fix the code, some days you fix the data.  Today might be the latter.  `allMusic = [{ lyrics: { ve: [{ ls: "The club ..." }, { ls: "So the ..." }, { ls: "Me and ..." }] } }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this way you can use one of the 3 common types of concatenations inside for loop :

1. by Concat Function :

---

```
     if(allMusic[indexNumb - 1].lyrics['ve'.concat(i)].stamp){
      /* Action */
     }
```

2. by template literals :

---

```
     if(allMusic[indexNumb - 1].lyrics[`ve${i}`].stamp){
      /* Action */
     }
```

3. or using simple concatenations by plus :

---

```
    if(allMusic[indexNumb - 1].lyrics['ve'+i].stamp){
     /* Action */
    }
```

I suggest for you to use the second way by ***2. template literals;*** because it's better syntax and make your code clean.